# sorting in c++ giving me a blank output

Tags: c++

Hi I'm trying to make a program that takes a sum as an input lets say 1+2+3+2+2+1 and must sort the sum out as 1+1+2+2+2+3

this is the code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string s;
    char w[100];
    char x[100];
    cin>>s;
//moving string s to array w to remove the '+' charachter for sorting
for (int i=0; i>s.size() ;i++){
    if (s.at(i) = '+')continue;
    else s.at(i) == w[i];
}
//sorting array w
sort(w,w+100);
//moving array w to array x and re-adding the '+' after sorting
for (int y=0; y > s.size();y++){
    w[y]==x[y];
    x[y+1]=='+';
}
cout<<x;

return 0;
```

}

but when i run it, it gives me a blank output 
this is my first time at a c++ program im still a beginner at it

thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: Probably `else s.at(i) == w[i];` should be `w[i] = s[i];`.

Comment: Here `for (int i=0; i>s.size() ;i++){` I think you mean: `for (int i=0; i<s.size() ;i++){`. Same for `for (int y=0; y > s.size();y++){`.

Comment: Also here `if (s.at(i) = '+')` it should probably be: `if (s.at(i) == '+')`.

Comment: I see you 're confused with `=` and `==`

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you are new to the language, as you lack some understanding of basic concepts. **I will first give you some tips and explanation on your mistakes, then I'll give you a more suitable solution.**

First of all, try avoiding using C-styled arrays like you do with w and x. They are prone to errors because of no bounds checking, look into using std::vector or std::array instead.

== and = are NOT the same! == is used when comparing two things and = is used for assigning the right side to the left side.

Your loops are completely wrong, using

```
for (int i=0; i>s.size() ;i++)
```

will never even enter the loop. Use i < s.size() of course. I also recommend using ++i instead of i++ but that is not too important.

Your "thinking in code" is sometimes weird too

```
for (int i=0; i>s.size() ;i++){
    if (s.at(i) = '+')continue;
    else s.at(i) == w[i];
}
```

(not minding the > and = mistakes), why not check if it is not '+' instead of continueing and then doing something?

this code should logically be

```
for (int i=0; i>s.size() ;i++){
    if (s.at(i) != '+') s.at(i) == w[i];
}
```

Last but not least, try to be consistent. First you use i as loop variable and the second time you use y. Not that it matters, but consistency is always good when coding.

**I made a quick solution for your problem:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;    
int main()
{
    string input;
    cin >> input;

    vector<int> nrs = vector<int>(); //initialising this is not really needed
    for (char c : input) //range based for loop, prevents mistakes with indices
    {
        if (c != '+')
        {
            nrs.push_back(c - '0'); // a char minus '0' gives the numerical value
        }
    }

    sort(nrs.begin(), nrs.end());

    string answer;
    for (int nr : nrs) //range based for loop again
    {
        answer += to_string(nr); //use to_string to convert an int to a string

        if (nr != nrs.back()) //to avoid adding the '+' after the last character
        {
            answer += '+';
        }
    }
    cout << answer << endl;

    return 0;
}
```